# How to solve kotlin type cast exception: null cannot be cast as null kotlin.collections.ArrayList

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and unable to solve this exception, I have tried different solutions from the net. I am fetching list of data from api and want to assign it to the spinner through databinding, but my code is crashing when I am assigning it to mutable arraylist in the success block of the api call.

this is my list declaration

```
private val _operators: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Networks>>? = NotNullMutableLiveData(arrayListOf())
val operators: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Networks>>? get() = _operators
```

Api call

```
fun getShops() {
    addToDisposable(api.getShoppingList().with()
        .doOnSubscribe {}
        .doOnSuccess {}
        .doOnError {}
        .subscribe({ result ->
             // getting crash here 
             _operators?.value = result.Data.get(0).items as ArrayList<Networks>
           
        }, { error ->
        })
    )
  }
```

Comment: can you please post your MobileNetworks pojo class ? and full stack trace of exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MobileNetworks` list is `null` to avoid `NPE` add `?` operator to check `Nullability`

```
 _operators?.value = result.PaymentMethods.get(0).mobileNetworks as 
                 ArrayList<MobileNetworks>?
```